# bootstrap and jquery both won't load not even the cdn links

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jumbotron").click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        })
    })
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

even if I right-click on the folder in vs code and click copy path/relative path and paste it in the href/src attributes they still won't load or work.... please tell me what to do./...

Comment: *"won't load or work"* is a little vague.  For starters, you **must** have `jquery.js` *before* `bootstrap.js`.  There *will* be errors in your browser console, include them in your question with an [edit].  Next check your browser network tab to see what's happening there - if you're getting a `404` then you have the wrong path.

Comment: Also note that your Javascript code needs to be contained within its own `<script></script>` tag. Right now it's a textnode child of the `head`, which will just be ignored.

Comment: @freedomn-m note that Bootstrap 5 no longer relies on jQuery.js, so the order of the scripts is ok in this case. The paths may be an issue though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the heads up regarding bootstrap 5.  Found this titbit: [jquery and bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible) - which indicates it's *advisable* to put jquery first, but, as you state, not required.   Can't edit my comment now, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code you've shown - assuming that the file paths are valid - is because you have placed the JS code in the wrong place. It needs to be contained within its own `<script />` tag in the `<head />`, not just as a textnode child.

Try the below example, noting that I used valid CDN links for the referenced scripts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jumbotron").click(function() {
          $(this).fadeOut();
        })
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works this way (missing script tags and change order) Please refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>        
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".jumbotron").click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            })
        });
      </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```